# Ray-Tracing Support

Tags: rendering

With the next line of NVIDIA cards being released soon, I was wondering, in what ways does blender support ray-tracing? The focus of these new cards seems to be the new ray-tracing capabilities.

Comment: Hi, I feel this is a bit off-topic here, and you should maybe ask blender devs, but I found this article about another engine, that has blender support, that explains well what could change: https://www.chaosgroup.com/blog/what-does-the-new-nvidia-rtx-hardware-mean-for-ray-tracing-gpu-rendering-v-ray. Of course getting improvements does not come free, in terms of time and money.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's much about new hardware and blender development

Answer (score 1):

Blender needs to specific implement code (see https://developer.nvidia.com/optix) in order to use the new hardware raytracing functionality. At the moment blender's raytracing is all software defined.

Ton has already been in talks with nVidia and they seem keen to help get it into blender (see https://www.blender.org/press/siggraph-2018-report/)